# React error : Invalid prop `class` supplied to React.Fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL4gr.png)

Hello, we are currently experiencing the following errors in React. I'm not sure what's wrong with this error and it's being sent out. I tried to cover it with a  tag instead of a <React.Fragment>, but the error above keeps appearing on the screen.

I think you're saying the wrong value is in the wrong tag. but I think, not found a problem with my code.

What could be wrong? I ask for your help me.

I attach my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import {
  POST_DETAIL_LOADING_REQUEST,
  POST_DELETE_REQUEST,
  USER_LOADING_REQUEST,
} from "../../redux/types";
import { Button, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import GrowingSpinner from "../../components/spinner/Spinner";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faPencilAlt,
  faCommentDots,
  faMouse,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import BallonEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor";
import BalloonEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor";
import { editorConfiguration } from "../../components/editor/EditorConfig";

const PostDetail = (req) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { postDetail, creatorId, title, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.post
  );
  const { userId, userName } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  console.log(req);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_DETAIL_LOADING_REQUEST,
      payload: req.match.params.id,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADING_REQUEST,
      payload: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    });
  });
  const onDeleteClick = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_DELETE_REQUEST,
      payload: {
        id: req.match.params.id,
        token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });
  };
  const EditButton = (
    <div>
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center pb-3">
        <Col className="col-md-3 mr-md-3">
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Home
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-md-3 mr-md-3">
          <Link
            to={`/post/${req.match.params.id}/edit`}
            className="btn btn-success btn-block"
          >
            Edit Post
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-md-3">
          <Button className="btn-block btn-danger" onClick={onDeleteClick}>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
  const HomeButton = (
    <div>
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center pb-3">
        <Col className="col-sm-12 com-md-3">
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Home
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
  const Body = (
    <div>
      {userId === creatorId ? EditButton : HomeButton}
      <Row className="border-bottom border-top border-primary p-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
        {(() => {
          if (postDetail && postDetail.creator) {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className="font-weight-bold text-big">
                  <span className="mr-3">
                    <Button color="info">
                      {postDetail.category.categoryName}
                    </Button>
                  </span>
                  {postDetail.title}
                </div>
                <div className="align-self-end">{postDetail.creator.name}</div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        })()}
      </Row>
      {postDetail && postDetail.comments ? (
        <div>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-baseline small">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} />
            &nbsp;
            <span> {postDetail.date}</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCommentDots} />
            &nbsp;
            <span>{postDetail.comments.length}</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMouse} />
            <span>{postDetail.views}</span>
          </div>
          <Row className="mb-3">
            <CKEditor
              editor={BalloonEditor}
              data={postDetail.contents}
              config={editorConfiguration}
              disabled="true"
            />
          </Row>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>hi</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet title={`Post | ${title}`} />
      {loading === true ? GrowingSpinner : Body}
    </div>
  );
};
export default PostDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a small syntax error, your final return statement should be :

```
return (
    <div>
      <Helmet title={`Post | ${title}`} />
      {loading === true ? <GrowingSpinner /> : <Body />}
    </div>
  );
```